# Reference C++ managed class library from C# class library

Tags: c#-4.0, managed-c++

How to reference class library from C++ managed? I can reference C++ managed library from another C++ managed library and use classes from it. But when i reference it from C# library it does not provide classes and namespaces from C++ (object browser show classes as well).

C++ Managed Class library1

```
namespace ns1{
    public ref class Class1{};
}
```

C++ Managed Class library2

```
using namespace ns1;
namespace ns2{
    public ref class class2{
    ns1::Class1 _cl;
};
}
```

And i can not do the same from C# class library.

---

VS 2010 can not reference C++ managed library from C# as 'Project reference'.
It is necessary to reference .dll file.

Comment: In `msvs2010` it is possible to reference `c++\cli` class library from `c#` project as a `Project reference`

Answer (score 0):

Did not you forget `public` keyword?

Class definition should look like this:

```
public ref class MyClass
{
}
```

to be accessible from another assembly.